# write different lines from an array to two different files

Tags: regex, perl

I have an output array from a command as follows

```
@flows = 

--------
Code: Message id 'com.test.mb.TestHarness' on execution group 'GENERALEG' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '6/4/13 9:54 AM' in Bar file '/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness_2013-06-04_09-54-  30.bar'
Last edited: '6/4/13 9:53 AM'.
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
Keywords:
--------
Code: Message id 'com.test.mb.TestHarness1' on execution group 'GENERALEG' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '10/5/13 9:56 AM' in Bar file '/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness1_2013-10-05_09-56-30.bar'
Last edited: '10/5/13 9:55 AM'.
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
Keywords:
--------
Code: Message id 'com.cims.utility.Test' on execution group 'GENERALEG' is stopped.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '5/20/13 4:27 AM' in Bar file '/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestDecodeDEV_2013-05-20_04-27-53.bar'
Last edited: '5/20/13 2:55 PM'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
Keywords:
```

There are a bunch of more similar lines.
My code is currently writing to a file the Text after Code:Message id ' and taking it's status.
My code

```
    open $file, '>>', "$LogDir/snglflows.txt";
foreach $_ (@flows)
{
 next if /^(\s)*$/;
 if (/Code: Message id '(.*?)' .* running/)
 {
  print $file "$1,started\n";
}
elsif (/Code: Message id '(.*?)' .* stopped/)
{
 print $file "$1,stopped\n";
}
}
close $file;
```

But this code is giving me the output to the snglflows.txt file as follows

```
 com.test.mb.TestHarness,started
 com.test.mb.TestHarness1,started
 com.cims.utility.Test,stopped
```

Is there a way i can get two files. one the snglflows.txt file and other one like flowbars.txt with with the bar file info as follows

```
/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness_2013-06-04_09-54-30.bar
/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness1_2013-10-05_09-56-30.bar
/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestDecode_2013-05-20_04-27-53.bar
```

Comment: You could do with being a bit clearer. What do you need in each of the files?

Comment: In one file, snglflows.txt I need output as `com.test.mb.TestHarness,started
 com.test.mb.TestHarness1,started
 com.cims.utility.Test,stopped` 

In the other file, flowbars.txt I need output as `/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness_2013-06-04_09-54-30.bar
/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestHarness1_2013-10-05_09-56-30.bar
/home/test/deploy/GENERALEG/TestDecode_2013-05-20_04-27-53.bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open another file and add a new elsif.

```
open $file, '>>', "$LogDir/snglflows.txt";
open $file2, '>>', "$LogDir/flowbars.txt";
foreach $_ (@flows)
{
    next if /^(\s)*$/;
    if (/Code: Message id '(.*?)' .* running/)
    {
            print $file "$1,started\n";
    }
    elsif (/Code: Message id '(.*?)' .* stopped/)
        {
            print $file "$1,stopped\n";
    }
    elsif (/Deployed: .* '(.*?)')
    {
            print $file2 "$1";
    }
}
close $file;
close $file2;
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to make a multi-line regexp to parse the record, but it's probably not necessary in this case.

Comment: I've never used multi-line regexp so i got no experience with them.